# How do i get data out of a while loop

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop

The title pretty much says it all.

I have a function that generates random RGB values which are converted to a colour.

I only want colours within a specific Luminance range so im using a while loop to create the RGB values, then check the luminance with the idea being that i want it to keep looping until it generates a colour within the luminance range.

My problem is that i can not work out how to get data out of the while loop to use as part of the overall function

Edit:
the below isn't working, the while loop isn't returning a value for randomcolor, Xcode just gives an error stating it's being used before its initialized. even if I move the return statement up into the for loop I just get an error for the overall statement advising I haven't returned a UIcolor. What I'm trying to do is get the colour value out of the while loop so it can be used outside the while loop.

```
func randomColor() -> UIColor{
    var randomRed:CGFloat
    var randomGreen:CGFloat
    var randomBlue: CGFloat
    var randomcolor: UIColor
    var lum: CGFloat = 0.0
    while lum < 50.0 {
        randomRed = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
        randomGreen = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
        randomBlue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
        lum = sqrt(randomRed * randomRed * 0.241 + randomGreen * randomGreen * 0.691 + randomBlue * randomBlue * 0.068)
        if lum > 50.0{
        let color = rC(randomRed: randomRed, randomBlue: randomBlue, randomGreen: randomGreen)
        randomcolor = color

        }
    }
    return randomcolor
}
```

Comment: The above doesnt work, the for loop doesnt set the value of random color, even if i move the return statement the overall function throws an error advising i havent returned a UIcolor

Comment: I don't know how much clearer I can be, I clearly stated that I can not get the value out of the loop which is what I'm trying to do. the errors all stem from the fact that i can't get the value out of the loop. my original question was how do i get the data out of the loop which is still the question. Don't be an ass because i added more information like you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are declaring variables at the start of your function, but not initialising them.  A value will be assigned to them inside the `while` loop, but the loop may execute zero times, resulting in `randomcolor` not being initialised before you attempt to reserve it.

Now, you and I can look at this code and see that `lum` is initialised with 0, so the `while` will execute at least once, but Swift doesn't work that way.  It just sees that the only assignment is inside a conditional block, so it gets upset.

You can simplify your code a little to, by getting rid of the `if` statement:

```
func randomColor() -> UIColor {
    var randomRed:CGFloat = 0.0
    var randomGreen:CGFloat = 0.0
    var randomBlue:CGFloat = 0.0
    var lum: Float = 0.0

    while lum < 50.0 {
        randomRed = CGFloat(Float(arc4random_uniform(256)))
        randomGreen = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
        randomBlue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
        lum = Float(sqrt(randomRed * randomRed * 0.241 + randomGreen * randomGreen * 0.691 + randomBlue * randomBlue * 0.068))
    }

    return rC(randomRed: randomRed, randomBlue: randomBlue, randomGreen: randomGreen)
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Cheers mate, am i always better off setting the value to 0 as opposed to leaving it empty?

Comment: One of the good things about Swift is that it tries to prevent mistakes that can lead to bugs later on, so if the compiler thinks you are using a variable before it is initialised then it will tell you.  You also could have declared the variables as optionals, so that the compiler knows that not having a value is OK, but then you would need to unwrap the optional each time you used it, so this way is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use repeat while true and only return the color if your condition is met.

Note: I have used UIColor just to illustrate the approach:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        repeat {
            let red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let green = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let blue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
            if sqrt( pow(red, 2) * 0.241 + pow(green, 2) * 0.691 + pow(blue, 2) * 0.068) > 50 {
                return UIColor(red: red / 255, green: green / 255, blue: blue / 255, alpha: 1)
            }
        } while true
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let color1: UIColor = .random  //  r 0.894 g 0.757 b 0.192 a 1.0
let color2: UIColor = .random  //  r 0.133 g 0.357 b 0.824 a 1.0
let color3: UIColor = .random  //  r 0.675 g 0.875 b 0.278 a 1.0
let color4: UIColor = .random  //  r 0.867 g 0.184 b 0.533 a 1.0
```

Comment: What's it checking back to to see if the statement is true?

Comment: It is an endless loop. It will always be true. It will only exit when it enters your condition and return the color

Comment: Sorry, im still in the early stages of learning how to code. So how would I make it false then and force it to exit the loop. is it the If statement you've put it that switches it to be false?

Comment: It breaks the loop (exit) as soon as you return the value. Note that it will only return the resulting color if it enters your minimum luminosity condition

Comment: Oh ok, that's awesome. Thankyou!